# Remotely/automatically delete entries

Tags: cognito-forms

I have Cognito Forms connected to a SharePoint list. Therefore I do not require the Cognito Forms entries.

Is there a way to remotely delete or delete after X days?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not offer a way to remotely delete or auto delete entries in Cognito Forms.